# What are my rights regarding to (female hygiene) bathroom facilities

Tags: offices, europe, netherlands

My company has just expanded and opened a new building next to the old one. My whole department moved into the new building.

This new building lacks (imo) good bathroom facilities. The toilet rolls are stacked on the floor, resulting in soggy rolls after the cleaners mop the floor. No towels, no handsoap and most important to me: no place to put used female hygiene products.

According to the office manager it's going to take another 3-4 weeks before we get all the products delivered.

I now have to walk to the other side of the building (a good 5 min walk) every time I need a sanitary bin. I find this highly annoying, not to mention a waste of my time and my boss' time. This is sometimes needed every hour.

What are my rights regarding to these kind of things? Can I 'demand' a sanitary bin and what if they refuse and make me wait?

Comment: Have you asked the company? Perhaps they are unaware.

Comment: @Ed Heal, I have asked the office manager who said nothing could be changed about the delivery times and that I could use another bathroom. Which is in this case quite far away.

Comment: I can only find UK regulation on it and it's not mandatory (Due to the keyword **should**): *"In the case of water closets used by women, suitable means should be provided for the disposal of sanitary dressings".* Someone will need to see if there is anything similar for the Netherlands

Comment: Sounds like they're just not interested in helping. It doesn't take 3-4 weeks to drive down to the local store and buy a bin. (Of course, it also doesn't take long to bring your own bin and put it there)

Comment: Plastic bags and kitchen roll + soap - a few Euros

Comment: @Erik They don't possibly see it as a problem that needs fixing now. I feel the OP needs to explain the issues that this causes to their management. But instead of working on the personnel need, maybe the loss in working hours caused by having to make these trips to the loo, in a different building? Do you have other women in the office? Do they also have the issue or found a different workaround? If they're all having the issue, many voices makes more of an impact than just one

Comment: @EdHeal You might need to look up the definition of sanitary products when it comes to ladies... Generally, sanitary bins are used to dispose of bodily waste that other people shouldn't come into contact with

Comment: @draken exactly, there is a need for special bins because otherwise the cleaner is nor allowed to empty them.

Comment: I looked it up, so if you want to rephrase this to just "*Is my Dutch employer required to provide sanitary bins?*" (which *is* on-topic), the answer is a flat **no.** Strategies for escalating the request is another on-topic question but "*how do I get this done?*" is something we can't answer as we don't know your company or the people involved.

Comment: 5 minutes stroll every hour is probably good for you... just saying

Answer (score 8):

You do have access to the appropriate sanitary facilities, unfortunately these are 5 minutes away temporarily. This isn't something I would push (if I was a woman). You have already tried and failed to get something done.

It's not really a subject you'd want to be known for (I assume) in the workplace.

So I suggest you soldier on for the interim and think of the 5 minute stroll as a chance to stretch and get some mild exercise. To me this seems more useful to have a change of attitude about it rather than battle over it.

Comment: Sadly the 5 min stroll becomes a 15 min scroll; 5 mins there, few mins toilet, 5 mins back. That's 15 mins I'm not working every hour or so. If I wait longer I could have leakage problems and this means a 15 min stroll through the whole company with stains on my pants.

Comment: Even better, take the 15 minutes, it's about how long smokers take an hour. You have the perfect pre-sanctioned excuse if your boss doesn't like it.

Comment: Yep, one does not wand to be known as "the pad protestor" or the "napkin natterer"  or any other nickname for protesting a policy.

Comment: @JohnDoe I think the main point is that this is a temporary inconvenience and management has a reasonable timeline to fix it. If you need to take 15 minutes every hour then do so, but don't feel the need to stay late to compensate for lost time. If you really feel like you're losing too much time you could always use the nearer bathroom and keep things in a plastic baggy for later disposal. Not the most fun solution, but again, this is temporary.

Comment: So, they get less work out of you for that period of time due to the problem they caused.  So long as you aren't blamed for the time lost you don't have much of a gripe.